# Is it valid to use future continuous for intention/coming event?

Tags: grammar, tenses, descriptive-grammar

In my native language, we can use future continous to say a thing we are going to do in a short time or right at that time. For example, my boss assigns me a task and I would answer (literally translate) **"I will be working on it right now"**.

For more context, it is used when I am about 90% sure that I start right at that time. But I may also finish whatever I am doing at that time, then start the assigned work later (but still in short time). That sentence is used to ensure my boss that: ok, I can do that, and I am going to do that and finish quickly.

Is it valid in English or is it weird (in either writing/speaking and formal/informal context)? What is the best and most common sentence/tense to say at that time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although your desire to use 'will' to reassure your boss is well-founded, there's a conflict between your present adverb ('right now') and your future verb tense.

A common solution is to use '[right away](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/right%20away)' to account for a slight delay in performing the action paired with the so-called future simple (which is arguably a present statement when coupled with a present adverb:

> 'I'll do it right away' (the situation you have described).
>
> 'I'll do it right now' (literally, in this very moment).

A more informal solution is to substitute 'get' for 'be':

> 'I'll get working on it right away.'

Answer (score -2):

"I will be working on it right now" is fine.

But you may also say : *"I will be working on it **ASAP.** or **in a little while** or **as soon as I (am) done (with) my actual task** or **right after** what I'm ending/finishing or **about to end now**"

Either versions : "I am or was just about to do it" or more direct "I'am about to be on it".

Comment: I am interested in this answer too, so could anyone downvoting please provide comment about the reason?

Comment: @DatVM : I knew it ! :) Your first version with a will + right now is OK because you haven't started yet to be on it... So don't worry, keep it so far we use it...

Comment: Although I haven't downvoted this one myself, I think the source of it is DAVE's assertion that "I will be working on it right now" is fine, which isn't quite true; as Egox pointed out, it causes a conflict between your present adverb and future verb tense.

Comment: We even could have : I'll be working on it, from now till....." Where "now" hasn't started yet but will in the next second . So it's a proximate future :)

Comment: The problem is that "right now" pretty unambiguously means "right at this exact moment"; it can't be anything but immediate present.

Comment: But till you haven't started to work on it, it remains future as you're not already on it ; which is the sole condition to preclude will/shall. But as soon you begin to do it you mustn't use will/shall as you're "on it" (present).